# How to download the content of a file from S3 bucket into memory with Ruby

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, bucket

I have a bucket in Amazon AWS S3 which has a file in it called `users.csv`.

How can I load the content of this file from the S3 bucket into memory with Ruby so I can parse it?

Here is my code:

```
require 'aws-sdk'
s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(region: 'us-west-1')
resp = s3.list_objects(bucket: 'bucket-name', max_keys: 1)
resp.contents.each do |object|
    puts #{object.value}
end
```

When I tried this in IRB I got:

```
struct Aws::S3::Types::Object key="users.csv", last_modified=2017-11-15 19:10:28 UTC, etag="\"9a3d50c07aa4aa6976037ce774294a26\"", size=101, storage_class="STANDARD", owner=struct Aws::S3::Types::Owner display_name="owner-name", id="42093cfa4ccb23a8156cdab8500a41a10bdbf90deebb0ee8a3b340dd1e0c3622"
```

How can I parse the content of `users.csv`?

Answer (score 8):

From the AWS Documentation:

> Downloading Objects into Memory
>
> For small objects, it can be useful to get an object and have it available in your Ruby processes. If you
>   do not specify a `:target` for the download, the entire object is loaded
>   into memory into a StringIO object.
>
> ```
> def import_from_s3 
>
>   #initiate the client
>   s3 = Aws::S3::Client.new({
>       region:            region,
>       access_key_id:     key_id,
>       secret_access_key: secret
>   })
>
>   #Get the object
>   resp = s3.get_object(bucket: bucket, key: key)
>
>  resp.body
>  #=> #<StringIO ...> 
>
>  resp.body.read
>  #=> '...'
> ```
>
> Call `#read` or `#string` on the StringIO to get the body as a String object.

For more information see "[Downloading Objects from Amazon S3 using the AWS SDK for Ruby](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/downloading-objects-from-amazon-s3-using-the-aws-sdk-for-ruby/)".

Comment: I get an error :   resp = s3.get_object(bucket:'bucket-name', key:'users.csv')
NoMethodError: undefined method `get_object' for #<Aws::S3::Resource:0x007ff9e6a4a2a8 @client=#<Aws::S3::Client>>
 from (irb):3
 from /Users/bdisha/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'

Comment: Hope you are using the v2 Ruby SDK (the aws-sdk-core gem) to download objects from Amazon S3.

Comment: here's the output of my gem list: ➜   ~ gem list aws-sdk

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

aws-sdk (3.0.1, 2.9.15, 2.5.6)

Comment: @Becks that error message says you're calling `get_object` on the `Resource` instead of the `Client`. The `Resource` API is for [working with buckets](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/S3/Resource.html), which isn't what you want to do here. If you call `get_object` on the `Client` object as ExploringApple's code suggests, it should work.