# How to execute bash scripts located on s3 bucket?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, amazon-s3

I have a script located on my s3 bucket. Can I execute that script on my instance by using the script bucket url or will I have to copy that script to my instance and then execute it?

Comment: Perhaps this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47317042/how-can-i-download-the-content-of-a-file-from-s3-bucket-into-memory-with-ruby Luis

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that you already have `awscli` on your EC2 instance (which should be in most of cases), this should work:

```
aws s3 cp s3://my-bucket/hello.sh - | bash
```

Answer (score -2):

You have download and then execute it. Though downloading and execution could be automated.

Create a sh file with following code, this just basic working example.

```
//assuming GET to your S3 assets is public.
curl full-path-of-sh.file > file_1.sh
sh file_1.sh
```